# How to assign a char in Xtend?

Tags: xtend

How can a variable of type `char` be assigned? I am looking for the Xtend equivalent of javas:

```
char c='?';
```

In Xtend the compiler reject all quotation marks like `'` or `"` because they produce a String:

```
var char c='?';
```

^ Error: *Incompatible types. Expected char or java.lang.Character but was java.lang.String*

Xtext Version is 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 2.4 you can write:

```
val char c = '?'
```

Comment: Of what type is `c` when no type is specified? 
`val c='?'`

Comment: Than it is still a String.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have to use '?'.charAt(0).

Comment: Ohh... nice! I thought you are kidding, but you are a Xtext commiter, so i think the answer is credible.

Is there a plan to get this fixed?

Comment: Yes, we will adress this issue in the release after 2.3. I expect that to be available in autumn.